# Why is a http2 connection closed instantly compared to a http1 keep-alive connection?

Tags: sockets, nginx, tcp, http2

Because the server of our browser game had a hard time to serve all clients after a downtime (lots of players refreshed the page till it was working again) I am trying to reduce the socket-connections. We had served the page with nginx 1.10.3 and used http 1.1 keep-alive connections. The backend of the game is served also with nginx 1.10.3 and uses http 1.1 connection (no keep-alive!). During this setup I saw a lot of TCP-Sockets in the `TIME_WAIT` state before they were finally closed. This is correct (see https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux).

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2 http2 is supported in every big browser and therefore I tried it out. As far as I know http2 reuses TCP-connections and therefore it is faster because the whole handshake part is skipped when there is already a working TCP-connection to the receiver (some other features make http2 also faster).

I used `netstat` to monitor all active internet connections and found out that sometimes only one connection is established with my pc and the server. All files (jpg, css, html, js) are transferred through this connection. But sometimes I see two or three connections. Does this mean that http2 may open more than one TCP-connection but it tries to optimize the reusage of them?

I also waited some minutes and checked `netstat` again and saw that only one TCP-connection is left open (all the others were closed). I closed the browser, refreshed `netstat` and the TCP-Connection was gone. But that shouldn't be possible, right? The connection/socket should still be there but now in the `TIME_WAIT`, `FIN_WAIT` or `CLOSED` state. Or does http2 allow/add a extremely fast socket closing mechanism?

Comment: Have you read [RFC 7540 Section 9.1 "Connection Management"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-9.1) yet?

Comment: Thanks, why didn't I come up with this myself... Just read it but it looks like not every browser does it like the RFC wants it, right? For example I used TCPView to check which sockets are opened. I used chrome 57 and firefox 52. When I use chrome and reload the page (CTRL + F5) the socket is reused. When I do this in firefox, the socket switches to the `TIME_WAIT` state and after a certain time is closed. In parallel a new socket is opened which is used.

Comment: Re *"I closed the browser, refreshed netstat and the TCP-Connection was gone. But that shouldn't be possible, right?"* - sure its possible. AFAIK, its also probable, and desirable. Merely navigating away from the page *can* be sufficient reason for browser to say "I don't need that connection any more" [mentioned in the linked RFC]; closing the browser *certainly* is such an event.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/

> The TCP connection can be closed by either peer. The END_STREAM flag
>   on a DATA frame is treated as being equivalent to the TCP FIN bit. A
>   client is expected to send a DATA frame with the END_STREAM flag set
>   after receiving a frame bearing the END_STREAM flag. A proxy that
>   receives a DATA frame with the END_STREAM flag set sends the attached
>   data with the FIN bit set on the last TCP segment. A proxy that
>   receives a TCP segment with the FIN bit set sends a DATA frame with
>   the END_STREAM flag set. Note that the final TCP segment or DATA frame
>   could be empty.

Also see `5.1 Stream States`. So, basically, there is no need in TCP TIME_WAIT state as end of stream is assured at a higher OSI level.